# I have issues with looping my vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following Macro that applies conditional formatting to a worksheet.  I want to apply this formatting to every worksheet in the workbook.  I dim the worksheet and included for Each and Next in my vba but it's not looping for every worksheet.

```
Sub Con()
Dim wkst As Worksheet

For Each wkst In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

 Range("B4:D4,G4,K4:M4").Select

With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
    Range("F1:J1").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 49407
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

Range("E8").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="E8>E9"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="E8<E9"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E8="""",E8=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E8:Q8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


Range("E11").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E11>E12"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E11<E12"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E11="""",E11=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E11:Q11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Range("E17").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E17>E18"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E17<E18"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E17="""",E17=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E17:Q17").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


'''----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''''

Range("E20").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E20>E21"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E20<E21"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E20="""",E20=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E20:Q20").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

'''----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''''
'''----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''''
'''----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''''

Range("E23").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E23>E24"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E23<E24"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E23="""",E23=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E23:Q23").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E26").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E26>E27"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E26<E27"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E26="""",E26=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E26:Q26").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E30").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E30>E31"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E30<E31"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E30="""",E30=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E30:Q30").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E42").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E42<E43"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E42>E43"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E42="""",E42=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E42:Q42").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E33").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E33>E34"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E33<E34"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E33="""",E33=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E33:Q33").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E39").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=E39>E40"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
    Formula1:="=E39<E40"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E39="""",E39=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E39:Q39").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is a macro I'm creating because I have a different macro that creates a temp workbook but ruins all the conditional formatting.  So I'm creating a macro that reapplies it.  Any assistance on how I can loop this would be great.

Comment: You need to qualify every range object with the worksheet variable.  `wkst.Range("B4:D4,G4,K4:M4").Select`

Comment: ...and then not use the `.Select` part or `Selection`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after your For Each statement to make it iterate through each sheet:

```
wkst.Activate
```

Disclaimer: Scott Craner and Comintern are right. Using Activate, .Select, and Selection results in slower and more error prone code. Follow their advice and you will have the best result in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an update on an answer to my question so I figured it out. It had nothing to do with the .Activate or .Select, I actually had to declare what is the active sheet.

```
Sub Con()
Dim sht As Worksheet, csheet As Worksheet
Call removecond
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set csheet = ActiveSheet
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If sht.Visible Then
sht.Activate
Range("E8").Select
 Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E8>E9"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E8<E9"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E8="""",E8=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E8:Q8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E11").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E11>E12"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E11<E12"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E11="""",E11=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E11:Q11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E17").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E17>E18"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E17<E18"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E17="""",E17=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E17:Q17").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E20").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E20>E21"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E20<E21"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E20="""",E20=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E20:Q20").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E23").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E23>E24"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E23<E24"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E23="""",E23=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E23:Q23").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E26").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E26>E27"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E26<E27"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E26="""",E26=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E26:Q26").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E30").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E30>E31"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E30<E31"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E30="""",E30=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E30:Q30").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E42").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E42<E43"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E42>E43"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E42="""",E42=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent3
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E42:Q42").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E33").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E33>E34"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E33<E34"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E33="""",E33=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E33:Q33").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Range("E39").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E39>E40"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 5287936
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=E39<E40"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(E39="""",E39=0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

Selection.Copy
Range("E39:Q39").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End If
Next sht
csheet.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```